# how to show sharepoint documents in salesforce?

Tags: integration, upload, contentdocument

How to show sharepoint documents in salesforce?

I should also be able to upload documents from salesforce directly to sharepoint if the users attach a document for a record in salesforce. Any idea how to achieve this?

I had a look at these links and it seems like a good way :

http://www.goldeninsights.com/2011/02/24/getting-sharepoint-to-talk-to-salesforce-on-the-cheap-part-1/#comment-6620

http://www.goldeninsights.com/2011/03/22/getting-sharepoint-to-talk-to-salesforce-on-the-cheap-part-ii/

But my sharepoint site is available only within the intranet, how can we link this to salesforce (as Salesforce is global and can be accessed from anywhere). What are the security measures that I need to look at and how to achieve this?

Ex:-
I have a record in salesforce account object. I have to attach a document for that record which should be directly uploaded to sharepoint and shouldnt exist in salesforce, but it should display the listview to the users once its uploaded to sharepoint and they should see them as if they exist inside salesforce, once they click on the link in the listview of the relatedlist, it should open the document from sharepoint.

Comment: You may need sharepoint admin access and also help from some one very familiar with sharepoint to accomplish this .

Answer (score 2):

I've done similar things with a product called [TRIM from HP](http://www8.hp.com/nz/en/software-solutions/software.html?compURI=1173707#.UW93vBy_3UY) rather than Sharepoint, but the basic principle is the same. In this case TRIM was accessible by users within the intranet and would hold the actual documents.

You create a custom object in Salesforce that can maintain the relationship between the Salesforce record and the unique identifier of the record stored in Sharepoint (probably a GUID).

You then create a formula field in Salesforce on the custom object that takes the GUID and creates a URL that the user within the intranet can access the sharepoint document with. For TRIM we were able to use a separate product called [TRIM Easy Link](http://kapish.com.au/products/trim-easy-link/).

The final part was to populate the relationship object in Salesforce when a document was uploaded to TRIM via the API.

There are a number of parts to such a solution, but it should work for Sharepoint as well.